# Forcing the status code from a jsp page

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have error.jsp which currently returns status 200 when I hit the URL with invalid URL like

```
http://myIP:8080/TestProject/Test?param1=junkxxxx
```

Is it possible to make the page return the status as 500

Comment: The easiest way would be to throw an exception, but why do you want to make it 500 when an invalid URL would be 400-level?

Comment: I already have the content in the JSP that shows the exception. However I would like to know if we can force change the status code too. Not necessorily 500 but even to anything else

Comment: Reffer this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JSP/0080__JSP_Server_Response.htm